# getting error upont inializing Intent

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

hello everyone in cyberspace.  I have had a problem that i just cant figure out for the life of me.  This little app is suppose to store my user name and passwords I click on a button the Button "Go to B" which initializes an intent to go to ActivityB in which I Press the "Load" Button and my user name and password shows up.

Now for the problem I get the following error every time I initialize the "Go to B" button (which calls a next method) see code below.

Not sure if it will help, but here is the xml for the "Go to B" Button

```
<Button
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Go to B"
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:background="#eee"
    android:onClick="next"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/save"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/save" />
```

Below code has been copied from MainActivity

```
public void next (View view)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Next", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I have placed Logs at the beginning of the Method and one at the end and realized the the error occurs at the "startActivity(intent)" because it never reaches the last log tag

here is the error

> Unable to find explicit activity class {com.tutorial.sharedpreferences/com.tutorial.sharedpreferences.ActivityB}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

currently I have (2) classes in my src folder (MainActivity and ActivityB) and in my layout folder I have (2) xml files (activity_main.xml and activity_b)

As a side note I have tried running this in Android Studio and Eclipse, it makes no difference.  The code has been copied from Android Studio

Comment: Post your `AndroidManifest.xml`. Most possibly, you haven't declared the `<activity>` for `ActivityB`

Comment: Andrew T you were right and >AndroidManifest> file was the problem. the problem was that I did not declare <activity> for ActivityB. Thanks to @Ziprox09 I was able to add the necessary code on the xml file and it works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this error :

```
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.tutorial.sharedpreferences/com.tutorial.sharedpreferences.ActivityB}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

check you `AndroidManifest.xml` , and add `ActivityB`  :

```
 <application

    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
     <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityB"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>
  </application>
```

Comment: everyone on this site is extremely helpful. Thank you Ziprox09 it is incredible how fast everyone here is able to diagnose a problem.  I hope I don't break an rules by saying this but DAMN your good.

Comment: Ziprox09, why is it that the xml file did not populate it self

Comment: @user3324600 I'm not really sure, but if you create a class and extending `Activity` manually, then the `<android>` tag won't be populated automatically. At least I can confirm it works in Eclipse using new Android Activity wizard (File-New-Other-Android-Android Activity)

Comment: Thanks, is the direction to the wizard the same for a Mac?